# Absolute imports in a TypeScript library packaged as ES modules with type declarations

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a library that is written in TypeScript and uses internally absolute imports to avoid deeply nested relative import statements, like

```
import {Something} from '../../../../root-level-module';
```

and instead write

```
import {Something} from 'root-level-module';
```

To get it to compile correctly, I use

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

in my `tsconfig.json`.

I am able to transform these import statements correctly in the emitted ES modules, using [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver#readme).

The npm package also includes the `.d.ts` type declaration files (1 per `.js` file) which are emitted using `tsc --emitDeclarationOnly`.

The problem is that the `import` statements in the declaration files are not transformed, so they cannot be read by the consumer of this package.

As far as I can see, TypeScript itself does not provide any way to emit the results of its internal path resolution mechanism: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

I tried some type declaration bundlers and some typescript transformers but couldn't get it to work correctly.

This is related to another particular issue with my library: it uses [babel-plugin-inline-react-svg](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg) to transform `SVG` files that are imported into React components. This is supported by a type declaration (`svg.d.ts`):

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  ...
}
```

The compiler understands import statements such as `import Icon from 'icon.svg';` correctly and they are correctly transformed by babel in the emitted `.js` files, but I am unable to get the type declaration files to be correct in a way that the library can be used by any other project.

So, am I missing something here? What would be the correct approach for writing a TypeScript library (as an NPM package) that:

1. is compiled into ES modules and not bundled
2. has type declarations (either bundled or not)
3. can use absolute imports internally (to avoid deeply nested relative imports)
4. can use the babel plugin to convert SVG files into React components
   ?